# nodejs install failing, says "Error executing command, exiting"

Tags: linux, node.js

The following command seems to be failing 
**curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -**

Just says **Error executing command, exiting**.
Does anybody know how i can find out what the issue is?

```
root@294183bd6f26:/# curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -

## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 10.x repo...


## Populating apt-get cache...

+ apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]
Ign:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [502 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2434 B]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [27.4 kB]
Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7082 kB]
Fetched 7918 kB in 2s (2958 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

## Installing packages required for setup: apt-transport-https lsb-release...

+ apt-get install -y apt-transport-https lsb-release > /dev/null 2>&1
Error executing command, exiting
```